# Tomcat does not compile jsp in work directory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat8

I am migrating a Spring-Boot application to a new server (Amazon-Linux). I could not deploy the application using Tomcat manager. Uploading the ROOT.war using the manager fails.

So, I deployed the application by manually uploading the ROOT.war. At first, it seemed that the deployment went well, the first page of the application (login) was loading. But after submitting the credentials, the application is not redirecting me to the home page. After investigation, it turned out that in the work directory (work/Catalina/............../WEB_002dINF/jsp/) there are only two files (my_login_jsp.class, my_login_jsp.java). So, does that mean compilation for other jsp files are being failed?

Please advise how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. There is something wrong with the Tomcat package that comes with amazon-linux-extras. 
After removing the aws package, now I am using Tomcat downloaded from the official website. The is working perfectly.